# Locator position as argument in ImageTrim

Tags: locator

I want to create a snippet that shows an image with two locators, and side-by-side with its crop based upon the position of the locators. Here is what I wrote. But it gives error that the list of locator positions "is not valid region of interest."

How can I solve this error? And is there other simple way of realizing what I want?

```
img = Import["ExampleData/spikey.tiff"];
DynamicModule[{pts = {{1, 1}, {100, 100}}},
{LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],img],ImageTrim[img,Dynamic[pts]]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `Dynamic` outside `ImageTrim`:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/spikey.tiff"];
DynamicModule[{pts = {{1, 1}, {100, 100}}},
  {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], img], Dynamic@ImageTrim[img, pts]}]
```

[image]

[Introduction to Dynamic >> Where Should Dynamic Be Placed in an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html):

- Because `Dynamic` does its work entirely in the front end, ***you cannot use it inside functions that need to access the value of an expression in order to do their work.***
- `Dynamic` is a formatting function that does its work in the front end, not in the kernel, so ***if it is used in a way where it will never be placed as output, it is probably a mistake.***

Comment: Nice. Now I understand.